# JS function when clicking parent element but return false when clicking child element

Tags: javascript

I have an image gallery on my site and when you click on it, it opens into a lightbox kind of effect.

I want them to be able to click off of the preview image on the lightbox background and close the preview but not if they click on the actual preview image itself.

```
function get_image_preview(){
    var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox");
    var image_src = document.getElementById("gallery_image").src;
    lightbox.style.display = "block";
    lightbox.setAttribute("onclick", "end_image_preview()");

    var new_image = document.createElement("img");
    new_image.setAttribute("id", "preview_image");
    new_image.setAttribute("src", image_src);
    new_image.setAttribute("onclick", "return false");
    lightbox.appendChild(new_image);
}
function end_image_preview(){
    var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox");
    lightbox.style.display = "none";
    lightbox.innerHTML = "";
}
```

So basically this line:

```
lightbox.setAttribute("onclick", "end_image_preview()");
```

does what it is supposed to do and close the preview.

However, the preview is a child of this and I want them to be able to click on the image without ending the preview, so I tried this:

```
new_image.setAttribute("onclick", "return false");
```

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle including all of your code (css/html/js)? Thx

Comment: This should not be done by adding an additional click handler on the image - but by checking what the original event _target_ was inside the first one you added. If that target was the image element - do nothing.

Comment: @stefanz SO has stacksnippets. Why leave the site to see an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mignt want to use [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

```
function new_image_click(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}

new_image.setAttribute("onclick", "new_image_click(event)");
```

Answer (score 0):

in your end image preview click listener make sure that the element does not have in its ancestor the preview element it self, lets say that you gave the preview element the id "preview"

in end_image_preview

```
function end_image_preview(e) {
   if (e.closest('#preview')) {
     return
   }

   // here do what you already doing
}
```